# reducing matrices under certain conditions

Tags: matlab, matrix

`M` is a matrix `4x2000000` composed of several submatrix `Ai` such that `Ai(1:3,j)` is the same vector for `j = 1,...,size(Ai,2)`. and `Ai(4,j)` are values between `1` and `100`.

```
V = [2 15 21 43]
```

my goal is to eliminate all sub-matrix `Ai` of `M`, if `Ai(4,:)` does not contain all the values of `V`.

**The only initial data for this problem** are `M` and `V`

Example:

```
M = [1022  3001  4451 1022 1022  3001 1022 3001 3001 1022;
      112    45    10  112  112    45   11   45   99  112;
      500    11    55  500  500    11   88   11    1  500;
        2     6     3    5   71     2    2   71    5   88]  

A1 = [1022 1022 1022 1022;
       112  112  112  112;
       500  500  500  500;
         2    5   71   88]

A2 = [3001 3001 3001;
        45   45   45;
        11   11   11;
         6    2   71]

A3 = [4451;
        10;
        55;
         3]

A4 = [1022;
        11;
        88;
         2]

A5 =[3001;
       99;
        1;
        5]
```

if `V = [2 71]`

The expected output (order of columns is not important):

```
[1022 1022 1022 1022 3001 3001 3001;
  112  112  112  112   45   45   45;
  500  500  500  500   11   11   11;
    2    5   71   88    6    2   71]
```

Comment: all values or any value?

Comment: @Divakar: all values

Comment: Post sample input data and expected output?

Comment: @Divakar: I added an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach -

```
[~,~,idx] = unique(M(1:3,:)','rows')  %//'
valid = ismember(M(4,:),V)
valid_idx = accumarray(idx(valid),M(4,valid).',[],@(x) ...
                                 numel(unique(x)))>=numel(V) %//'
out = M(:,ismember(idx,find(valid_idx)))
```

Comment: I particularly like the second one!

Comment: @bzak There was a bug, fixed that. Basically if the fifth column had something other than `71` in the fourth row, it was still considering `A1` into the output, which was wrong. It's all good now!

Comment: @Divakar: How to replace V with a choice between two or more vectors.  instead of V, there will  {V1 or V2 or ..} ?

Comment: @bzak Store `V1`, `V2`, etc in a cell array and then use a loop to get outputs for all V's and store them. Then, after the loop ends, one can choose, Would this work? If all V's are same sized, you can use a numeric array instead of cell array.

Comment: @Divakar: Can i avoid the loop, because the calculation time increases with the size of the cell !!!

Comment: @bzak Are those `V1`, `V2`, etc. same sized?

Comment: @Divakar: No, different size!

Comment: @bzak Consider posting that as a new question, because it would require wholesome changes to the existing solution.

Comment: @Divakar : Please, what i have to change in the code if the question was: my goal is to eliminate all sub-matrix Ai of M, if Ai(4,:) does not contains at least numel(V)-2  values of V.