# reducing matrices under certain conditions - Part 2 -

Tags: matlab, matrix

**This question is more complex than [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29473620/reducing-matrices-under-certain-conditions) because here V is a cell**

`M` is a matrix `4x2000000` composed of several submatrix Ai such that Ai(1:3,j) is the same vector for `j = 1,...,size(Ai,2)`. and `Ai(4,j)` are values between `1` and `100`.

```
V = {V1,V2,...,Vn}  (V1 or V2 or ...Vn)
```

`V1,V2,... and Vn` have different sizes.

my goal is to eliminate all sub-matrix `Ai` of `M`, if `Ai(4,:)` does not contain all the values of `V1 or V2 or ...Vn`.

**The only initial data for this problem** are `M` and `V`

I wanted to use a for loop with the answer of the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29473620/reducing-matrices-under-certain-conditions), but I noticed that the calculation time increases with the size of V.

Example:

```
M = [1022  3001  4451 1022 1022  3001 1022 3001 3001 1022 1055 1055 1055 1055 1055 1055;
      112    45    10  112  112    45   11   45   99  112   11   11   11   11   11   11;
      500    11    55  500  500    11   88   11    1  500   45   45   45   45   45   45;
        2     6     3    5   71     2    2   71    5   88    8   15   21   94   10   33] 



A1 = [1022 1022 1022 1022;
       112  112  112  112;
       500  500  500  500;
         2    5   71   88]

A2 = [3001 3001 3001;
        45   45   45;
        11   11   11;
         6    2   71]

A3 = [4451;
        10;
        55;
         3]

A4 = [1055 1055 1055 1055 1055 1055;
        11   11   11   11   11   11;
        45   45   45   45   45   45;
         8   15   21   94   10   33]

A5 =[3001;
       99;
        1;
        5]

if V = {[2 71],[3],[15 94 33 10]}
```

The expected output (order of columns is not important):

```
[1022 1022 1022 1022 3001 3001 3001 4451 1055 1055 1055 1055 1055 1055;
  112  112  112  112   45   45   45   10   11   11   11   11   11   11;
  500  500  500  500   11   11   11   55   45   45   45   45   45   45;
    2    5   71   88    6    2   71    3    8   15   21   94   10   33]
```

Comment: That `or` between `V1` and `V2`, and between `V2` and `V3` and so on might be a bit confusing. Why not use some sample input `V1`, `V2`, etc. and also copy over the other sample inputs `M`, `V` used in the linked question onto here and then tell us the expected output?

Comment: @Divakar: I added the example

Comment: possible duplicate of [reducing matrices under certain conditions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29473620/reducing-matrices-under-certain-conditions)

Comment: Except for some different values in the example data this is exactly the same question as your previous one!

Comment: @knedlsepp: No, here V is a cell. I wanted to use a for loop with the answer of my previous question, but I noticed that the calculation time increases with the size of V. Here, I hope to find a solution without loop.

Comment: What does *does not contain all the values of `V`* even mean in this context?

Comment: @knedlsepp: Sorry, i meant V1 or V2 or ...Vn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works for you -

```
%// ID columns of M based on the uniquenes of the first thre rows
[~,~,idx] = unique(M(1:3,:).','rows')  %//'

%// Lengths of each V cell
lens = cellfun('length',V)

%// Setup ID array for use with ACCUMARRAY later on
id = zeros(1,sum(lens))
id(cumsum(lens(1:end-1))+1) = 1
id = cumsum(id)+1

%// Collect all cells of V as a 1D numeric array
Vn = [V{:}]

%// Counts of number of elements for each cell/groups of V
counts_V = histc(id,1:numel(V))

%// Function handle to detect for if the input would satisfy the crietria
%// of all its values belong to either V1 or V2 or ...Vn
func1 = @(x) any(counts_V == histc(id(ismember(Vn,x)),1:numel(V)))

%// For each ID in "idx", see if it satisfies the above mentioned criteria
matches = accumarray(idx(:),M(4,:)',[], func1 )  %//'

%// Use the "detections" for selecting the valid columns from M
out = M(:,ismember(idx,find(matches)))
```

Comment: I do not know if I can abuse your kindness to ask you if it's easy to connect the two parts 2 and 3?!

Comment: @bzak Hmm that might get a bit more complicated and would require good changes to the existing code. Post a new question on it?

Comment: Ok i will do it, but I'm afraid of receiving negative comments !!

Comment: @bzak See if this edit makes it work - `func1 = @(x) any(counts_V-2 <=  histc(id(ismember(Vn,x)),1:numel(V)))`?

Comment: I think it works, I'll do other test!  Thank you very much  Divakar for the time you spend on my questions!

Comment: @bzak No problem really! Don't worry about the downvotes you get, I do find your questions to be challenging and interesting, keep it up!