# reducing matrices under certain conditions -Part 3-

Tags: matlab, matrix

`M` is a matrix composed of several submatrix `Ai` such that `Ai(1:3,j)` is the same vector for `j = 1,...,size(Ai,2)`

```
M = [1022  3001  4451 1022 1022  3001 3001 1022 4451 1022;
      112    45    10  112  112    45   45  112   10   11;
      500    11    55  500  500    11   11  500   55   88;
        2     6     6    5   71     2   71   88    2    2]



A1 = [1022 1022 1022 1022;
       112  112  112  112;
       500  500  500  500;
         2    5   71   88]

A2 = [3001 3001 3001;
        45   45   45;
        11   11   11;
         6    2   71]

A3 = [4451 4451;
        10   10;
        55   55;
         6    2]

A4 = [1022;
        11;
        88;
         2]

V = [2 71 6 9]
```

The only initial data for this problem are `M` and `V`.

**my goal is** to eliminate all sub-matrix `Ai` of `M`, if `Ai(4,:)` does not contains at least `numel(V)-2` values of `V`.

for my example `A1`, `A2` and `A3` verify this condition.
The expected output (order of columns is not important):

```
[1022 1022 1022 1022 3001 3001 3001 4451 4451 ;
  112  112  112  112   45   45   45   10   10;
  500  500  500  500   11   11   11   55   55;
    2    5   71   88    6    2   71    6    2]
```

how to change the following [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29473620/reducing-matrices-under-certain-conditions) to solve my problem:

```
[~,~,idx] = unique(M(1:3,:)','rows')  %//'
valid = ismember(M(4,:),V)
valid_idx = accumarray(idx(valid),M(4,valid).',[],@(x) ...
                                 numel(unique(x)))>=numel(V) %//'
out = M(:,ismember(idx,find(valid_idx)))
```

Comment: The number 5 is not part of `V` yet it's part of the final output seen in `M(4,:)`.  Also, 2, 71, and 6 have at least two values in `M(4,:)` and those aren't eliminated either which we expect.  9 is also not part of `M(4,:)` so we expect that nothing happens.  Can you please verify your desired output to see if this coincides?  Also, can you double check to see if my understanding of your problem is correct?

Comment: @rayryeng: my goal is to eliminate all sub-matrix Ai of M, if Ai(4,:) does not contains at least numel(V)-2 values of V!  5 is not part of V, but in my example  numel(V)-2=2. So, Ai(4,:) should contains at least 2 values of V.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works for you -

```
%// ID columns of M based on the uniquenes of the first thre rows
[~,~,idx] = unique(M(1:3,:).','rows')  %//'

%// For each ID detect if it satisfies the ">= numel(V)-2" criteria 
matches = accumarray(idx(:),M(4,:)',[],@(x) sum(ismember(V,x))>=numel(V)-2 )

%// Use the valid ID's to select the valid unique groups for desired output
out = M(:,ismember(idx,find(matches)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much Divakar. I tried to draw inspiration from one of your old answers, but the running time was too large!! I still can not understand some parts of the codes!

Comment: great! instead of waiting for 1000 seconds, your code will execute in 9 seconds!